# new to android - how to display text than picture in rows

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to display all the pictures taken by a camera and arrange them by date. So, I would like the screen to look something like this:

2011

picture1 picture2 picture3

2012

picture1 picture2 picture3

2013

picture1 picture2 picture3

I tried to look through some tutorials, but could not find anything...

Comment: [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Comment: cuz im new, can you slap some code down :)

Comment: Can I "slap some code down"? No. But now you have somewhere to start. Look up a tutorial and repost when you have a more specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with a custom layout. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).